# Слова, имеющие широкое и узкое значение - название?

Tags: значение-слов, смысл

Как называются слова, которые имеют узкий и широкий смысл? Например, слова: "общество", "государство" и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Многозначные. По крайней мере слово общество.

А вот слово государство однозначное, это политическая организация общества, не поняла, какое у него узкое значение. Может быть, Вы имели в виду метонимию? Государство призывает что-то сделать, а имеется в виду группа политических деятелей на службе у государства? Как "класс засмеялся", а подразумевается, что ученики класса смеются.

Comment: Я думаю, тут государство - страна и государство - политическое устройство. Многими это воспринимается как широкое и узкое значение (даже теми, кто таких терминов не знает - на подсознании). Смотрите, даже на карте обозначены *государства*, хотя на самом деле там всего лишь государственная принадлежность территорий.